# PHP MongoClient connecting to 2 separate databases on separate servers

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I'm trying to connect to 2 different databases on different servers, but it seems as if the driver mixes the connections up.

```
<?php
$mongo1 = new MongoClient("mongodb://old-server1.com:27017,old-server2.com:27017", array('replicaSet' => 'repset1'));

$mongo1->selectDB('oldDB');
$data1 = $mongo1->myinfo->find();

$mongo2 = new MongoClient("mongodb://new-server1.com:27017,new-server2.com:27017", array('replicaSet' => 'repset2'));
$mongo2->selectDB('newDB');
$data2 = $mongo2->myinfo->find();
```

When I run this script multiple times without changing anything. Sometimes $data1 will be from $mongo1 and sometimes from $mongo2. So on some occasions $data1 will match $data2 when the same server is used for both connections($mongo1 and $mongo2), and other times the 2 servers connections will be used individually as expected and produce different data sets.

Does any one know why happens. The same script will return different results when ran at odd intervals. Almost as if when cache expires i'll get the expected results and then directly afterwards it will be different again.

Comment: What version of the MongoDB PHP driver are you using?